# Parse.com is not able to retrieve data when wifi is turned OFF on my phone

Tags: android, parse-platform, ionic-framework

My app is written using Ionic Framework.  It uses Parse.com for storage (read/write).  App works fine and retrieves data via parse when it is on wifi for both running on desktop and deployed as an Android app on the phone.  However, when switch off wifi on Android phone and uses carrier network, parse is not returning any data,  is set.  Any idea?

Comment: Looking at the linked questions in the sidebar, the most common flaw seems to be not using `<access origin="*" />`, whatever that means. Have you checked that? Otherwise, you have not provided enough information for anyone to really help you - indeed, it's not even clear if the problem is when wifi is on (title) or off (message body)!

Comment: My bad, I meant when wifi is turned off.  Yes, I have included <access irugub="*" />